# Calendar similar to ical, which supports reminders without opening software

Tags: calendar

I am looking for a calendar software which is light on memory and cpu usage, something like ical, but on windows. I also want to get reminders of appointments/tasks at OS level... What I meant is that I should be able to get reminded without opening the software, something which ical does...

I tried Microsoft Outlook 2010, but it works only when you open outlook
By the way, I use Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I think VueMinder Calendar Lite will do what you're looking for. It loads as a background process when Windows starts, and will provide reminders without needing to be opened.

On my system, it uses only around 8 MB of RAM and Process Lasso shows average CPU usage over several hours to be one-tenth of one percent when it's running in the background.

It's pretty amazing how much cool stuff has been crammed into it, while hardly using any CPU or memory. Even better - it's free!
http://www.vueminder.com